# WxPython - Inaccurate modal windows behavior

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython

I encounter some annoying behavior with modal frames in WxPython.
As we all know, when a modal window shows up, it appears on foreground (on top of the main window) and the main window should become inaccessible (no response to click for example).

This is working as expected with nested WxFrames until using the Windows start (status)bar.
If user clicks on main frame on Windows bar, it appears on top of the second frame, which is totally inaccurate as user does not understand what's happening and why the window is inaccessible.

The first solution coming on my mind is to bind activation event of the first frame, and set programmatically (& systematically) the second frame to foreground. However it appears to me weird that this behavior is not already done naturally by WxPython.

Does anyone have any idea or any native / generic solution for that?

Comment: "nested modal frames" sounds like a terrible idea from the start. You could well end in the confusing position of hunting for one that actually has focus.

Comment: Forget about the word "nested"! I'll remove this word from the title if it's confusing. This problem occurs even with only "one" modal frame and I don't think it's a terrible idea to use a modal window.

Comment: A modal window blocks all other workflows in the top-level program until the modal window is closed. Modal windows are intended to grab the user's full attention.Users may not recognize that a modal window requires their attention, leading to confusion about the main window being non-responsive. In severe cases, the modal window appears behind another window controlled by the same program, potentially rendering the entire program unresponsive until the modal window can be located manually. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window

Comment: So? You just tell me the definition of a modal window (which I have already told in my question). I'm not sure if you understood the problem.
The active window (i.e. Modal window) should not go behind the main window (which is non-responsive). Which is happening with wxFrame.

Comment: Not only to I understand the problem, I also understand that what you are describing is a function of the operating system that you are using, not wxpython.

Comment: Operating system? I'm developing C++, C# and Python application by using a same computer (so the same operating system) and this problem occurs only with Python applications.

Answer (score 0):

As I suggested in my question, I binded activate event I raise all children window. This works as expected. We can first go to top level window and starting to raise from the first window to raise always all children frames. But always it's strange for me that it's not managed naturally by wxPython.

```
def __init__(self, parent):
   wx.Frame.__init__(...)
   ...
   self.Bind(wx.EVT_ACTIVATE, self.on_activate_window)

def on_activate_window(self, event):
    """
    Set modal windows to foreground by their hierarchical order
    """
    self.set_children_to_top(self.GetChildren())

def set_children_to_top(self, children):
    """
    Loops all children of the given windows, if any other modal window is found, it raises the new window to foreground
    """
    for child in children:
        if isinstance(child, wx.Frame) and child.is_modal:
            child.Raise()
        try:
            child_window = child.GetChildren()
            if child_window:
                self.set_children_to_top(child_window)
        except AttributeError:
            continue
```

Answer (score 0):

It is much better to use `wx.Dialog` when you need a modal window, as it is designed from the start to behave that way. In fact, because of the inconsistencies the `MakeModal` method has been removed for frames, although if you really need to do it that way there is a workaround.

Comment: We have a huge project where we have lot of wxFrame. So I don't think that would be safe and easy to migrate all of them to wxDialog (honestly I prefer my workaround)
Beside, as far as I know wxFrame is designed to be the main window of an app, with a menubar, toolbar and statusbar. All these features are not natively supported by wxDialog.